# How I can insert the current date in Google Docs when I make a new file?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace

How to insert the current date (in place where I want)  when you open new document as a template in Google Docs?

I make 10 Doc's templates and in each insert pattern, for example dd-mm-yyyy and I want if I open new Document from template this pattern (dd-mm-yyyy) automatically be changes to current date (23-08-2018).

And how to install this script for all people in my organization so that when they open this template, everyone has the correct date?

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm find solution:

`
** // it find in your Doc letters 'Date:' and change it to today date '07-09-2018' **

function replaceDate(){
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var d = new Date();
  var pattern = 'Date:';
 var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT", "dd-MM-yyy"); 
 body.replaceText(pattern, todayDate) ;
}
`